# Multiple SSO integration with different idp

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, saml-2.0, opensaml

I am new to this all SSO thing and I am using grails-plugin to integrate multiple IDP in my application. For single IDP it works fine but when I try to add more than one IDP it gives me error like

`Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception [org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Metadata for entity <entityID> and role {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}IDPSSODescriptor wasn't found] with root cause
Message: Metadata for entity <entityID> and role {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}IDPSSODescriptor wasn't found`

It doesn't matter which IDP I use, only the last entry works and for rest of them it gives me the same error.

It seems it takes the sp alias and save the last entry for it and serve for that.

Also, in logs I get `Index for AssertionConsumerService not specified, returning default` if it is of any help.

I know it takes the correct idp as it shows in the logs `context.SAMLContextProviderImpl  - Using user specified IDP <entityID> from request`

Please help I am stuck on this for long

Comment: Are you referring to spring-security-saml as your grails-plugin? If so what version?

Comment: @JasonHeithoff I am suing org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.0.RC2

Comment: Try a newer version, 1.0.4.RELEASE is the latest, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/releases. This issue may have been resolved in 2015: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/130 not sure its the same problem you presented. 1.0.0.RC2 was released in 2013. There is also a grails equivalent plugin: https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/jeffwils/spring-security-saml It may have better support for multiple IDPs.

Comment: No, @JasonHeithoff that was not the problem, thanks for responding though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, I was using mulitple idp files but all idp files should be in a single file and should be under EntitiesDescriptor root tag. Missed that part.